# Probability of a trajectory in Markov processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, statistical-mechanics

I need help with a simple formula! (My question is taken from [here](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/17/60/63/PDF/LESHOUCHES_COURS.pdf), pag 26 eq 1.112. )

Consider a Markov Process with associated Master Equation:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dP\left(C,t\right)}{dt}=\sum_{C'\neq C}W\left(C,C'\right)P\left(C',t\right)-\sum_{C'\neq C}W\left(C',C\right)P\left(C,t\right)
\end{equation*}
where

- $C$: configuration of the system
- $P\left(C,t\right)$: probability of being in configuration $C$ at
  time $t$
- $W\left(C',C\right)$: transition rates

> My question is: how can I prove the following formula?
>
> \begin{equation*}
> P\left(C_{1},...,C_{k};t_{1},...,t_{k}\right)=Ke^{t_{k}\mathcal{W}\left(C_{k},C_{k}\right)}...e^{t_{1}\mathcal{W}\left(C_{1},C_{1}\right)}W\left(C_{k},C_{k-1}\right)...W\left(C_{2},C_{1}\right)P_{\text{eq}}\left(C_{1}\right)
> \end{equation*}

where

- $K$: is a normalisation constant
- $\mathcal{W}\left(C,C\right)=-\sum_{C'\neq C}W\left(C',C\right)$
- $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}P\left(C,t\right)=P_{\text{eq}}\left(C_1\right)$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Equation (1.110) does not consider $\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W(C,C')}$ but the quantities $[\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W}](C,C')$. The difference is that the matrix $A_t=\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W}$ is defined as the sum of the matrix series
$$
A_t=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{t^n}{n!}\,\mathcal W^n,
$$
hence, for every $(C,C')$,
$$
A_t(C,C')=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{t^n}{n!}\,\mathcal W^n(C,C').
$$
A little earlier in the text, $A_t$ is introduced as
$$
A_t(C,C')=P(C',t\mid C,0).
$$

> My question is: how can I prove the following formula?
>
> \begin{equation*}
> P\left(C_{1},...,C_{k};t_{1},...,t_{k}\right)=Ke^{t_{k}\mathcal{W}\left(C_{k},C_{k}\right)}...e^{t_{1}\mathcal{W}\left(C_{1},C_{1}\right)}W\left(C_{k},C_{k-1}\right)...W\left(C_{2},C_{1}\right)P_{\text{eq}}\left(C_{1}\right)
> \end{equation*}

This (equation (1.112)) is considering the *density of a joint distribution*. To understand this point, consider  $\Delta_k=(\mathbb R_+)^k$ and $\mathcal C$ the set of configurations. Then the RHS of (1.112) is the joint density on $\mathcal C^k\times\Delta_k$ of the $k$ first different configurations and of the times spent in them by the system. This is explained in the paragraph of text just before (1.112).

Thus, (1.112) is correct, the exponentials in (1.112) are really $\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W(C_i,C_i)}$, not  $[\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W}](C_i,C_i)$, the quantities $\mathcal W(C_i,C_i)$ in the exponentials are defined by (1.108) and each $-\mathcal W(C_i,C_i)$ represents the total rate at which the system leaves state $C_i$. According to me, the factor $K$ should read
$$
K=-\mathcal W(C_k,C_k).
$$
With this convention and using the notation $\xi_{i:j}$ as a shorthand for $(\xi_i,\xi_{i+1},\ldots,\xi_j)$ for every symbol $\xi$ and every integers $i\leqslant j$, note that
$$
\int_0^\infty\sum_{C_k}P(C_{1:k};t_{1:k})\mathrm dt_k=P(C_{1:k-1};t_{1:k-1}).
$$
In the end, and interpreting with care the various quantities involved, I see only (1.107) as problematic. Replacing (1.107) by the condition that $\mathcal W(C,C')=W(C,C')$ for every $C\ne C'$ saves the day. Of course, one can complain that the fact that $P(C_{1:k};t_{1:k})$ is a *density* is not even mentioned and that the notations are rather confusing, but...

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Maybe the author uses a shorthand notation in eq.1.112 for eq.1.110? Unfortunately I still don't understand how to obtain eq. 1.112 :-(

Comment: Thanks again for the edit! Things are more clear now! However, probably for my lack of basic knowledge, I don't understand why the probability distribution for the time goes with an exponential (e^W).

Comment: Because $\mathrm dP_t/\mathrm t=\mathcal W\cdot P_t$ (this is a rewriting of your first displayed "Master equation"). With the initial condition $P_0=I$, this dynamics is solved by $P_t=\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W}$, that is, $P_t(C,C')=[\mathrm e^{t\mathcal W}](C,C')$ for every $C$ and $C'$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it XD! In my mind I have also that, for 2 configurations only as an example, $P(C_2,t_2;C_1,t_1)=P(C_2,t_2|C_1,t_1)P_{\text{eq}}(C_1)$. Thus $P(C_2,t_2|C_1,t_1)=Ke^{t_2\mathcal{W(C_2,C_2)}}e^{t_2\mathcal{W(C_1,C_1)}}W(C_2,C_1)$ which I don't know how to justify from the master equation (also from the one integrated in operator form).

Comment: Sorry I meant: $P(C_2,t_2|C_1,t_1)=Ke^{t_2\mathcal{W}(C_2,C_2)}W(C_2,C_1)$ and $P_{\text{eq}}(C_1)=e^{t_1\mathcal{W}(C_1,C_1)}$

Comment: I was thinking that one can say that the joint distribution is made up of the product of two probabilities: the transition probability (probability of moving from one state to another one) and the probability of holding time (that is the probability of remaining in a certain state for a certain time; see "Markov Chains" - Norris page 70 for holding time prob).

Comment: Sorry but you cannot continue to mix everything with everything like that. What is $P(C_2,t_2;C_1,t_1)$ to you? Note that this notation does not appear in your question nor in my answer. I took pain to define **precisely** $P(C_1,C_2;t_1,t_2)$ (not $P(C_2,t_2;C_1,t_1)$...) and only then, was able to deduce results about these quantities.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't want to be disrespectful of your work (which indeed helped me a lot). The probability of a trajectory (which in principle is 0 since time is continuous, so we should speak of its density) can be obtained as (having in mind the idea of considering configuration and time in terms of two different random variable giving rise to a joint probability):

Comment: $P\left(C_{1},...,C_{k};t_{1},...,t_{k}\right)=$
$P\left(\left(C_{1},t_{1}\right)\rightarrow\left(C_{2},t_{2}\right)\rightarrow...\rightarrow\left(C_{k},t_{k}\right)\right)=$
$\prod_{i=1}^{k}P\left(C_{i}\rightarrow C_{i+1},t_{i}\right)=$
$\prod_{i=1}^{k}P\left(C_{i}\rightarrow C_{i+1}\right)P\left(\tau>t_{i}\right)=$
$\prod_{i=1}^{k}d\tau_{i}W\left(C_{i},C_{i+1}\right)e^{-t_{i}\sum_{C'\neq C}W\left(C',C_{i}\right)}$

where $\tau$ is the time and $t_i$ are the holding times.